# Can i use coils with compressed air to make a superconductor?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, pressure, air, superconductivity

What im saying is inside pipes i am going to use compressing so that that in the places with low pressure they cool the superconducotor. is this possible? Can i use this concept to make superconductors or at least sustain them for extended periods?

If anything is unclear please comment and I'll correct it.

but will it be great enough to cool the superconductor to the point it needs and would it extend the time it stays a superconductor?

Comment: Are you asking if you can cool metals with expanding air? If so the answer is trivially yes. Are you asking if placing metals inside compressed air will cool them down? The answer to this is no.

Comment: but will it be great enough to cool the superconductor to the point it needs and would it extend the time it stays a superconductor?

Comment: what is the system? Describe it precisely, and then you can get an answer. There is no question here. Also, any interpretation I give where the question is precise, the answer is obvious.

Comment: ok im going to make a tear drop ROV that under the outer layer has superconducters. behind that outerlayer is a empty space with pipes hocked to a several compressers. inside thes pipes im going to lower the pressure of these pipes whenever they are on the outside of the iner most layer. on the inside ill have the comperssers moving the highcompressed air into the innermost layer while the outermost layer it becomes low pressurized to try to cool the superconducters

Comment: I get it now--- your major problem is the superconductors have a maximum current--- check that the maximum current will be enough, it probably won't. Cooling the magnets shouldn't be a problem with the proper insulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is by properly insulating your machine so as to require less energy to be spent on cooling. The other major problem you will have is you need to figure out what super conductor you want to use. For example, $\text{Hg}\,\text{Ba}_2\text{Ca}_2\text{Cu}_3\text{O}_{8+δ}$ is able to reach this state at 133 Kelvin, which is a reasonable temperature to maintain, though you should also consider cost.